# Possible errata in Nicolas Bourbaki's General Topology -I, Chapter 1 Exercise 2 ?

Tags: gn.general-topology, books, bourbaki

Here is the text of Exercise:

2 a) Let $X$ be an *ordered* set. Show that the set of intervals

$\left[x, \rightarrow\right[$       (resp. $\left]\leftarrow, x\right]$)

is a base of topology on $X$; this topology is called the *right* (resp. *left*) topology of $X$. In the right topology, any intersection of open sets is an open set, and the closure of $\{x\}$ is the interval $\left]\leftarrow, x\right]  $.

---

The above one was from English edition. I translated French edition and found the same text.

---

Should not be $X$ a **totally** ordered set ? And is not that the set of intervals should be  $\left]x, \rightarrow\right[$   in place of $\left[x, \rightarrow\right[$ ?

Is this an errata ?

Comment: Look for Bourbaki's definition of "ordered".


Comment: I looked it up, and "order" does, indeed, mean partial order.

Comment: errata = a list of errors in a published work. So it's not an "errata", but possibly (at most) an error. But I don't think it is, it's correct as stated.

Comment: erratum is the singular form. :)

Comment: Still I would also suggest to avoid using *erratum* in this form, as it is my impression its standard meaning in academic writing is a bit different from the pure translation 'error'; often referring to some (informally) published note pointing out and possibly fixing an error.

 

Comment: Somewhere there is a book in which page 342 is headlined "Errata", and the text reads, in its entirety:  "On page 342, change 'Errata' to 'Erratum' ".

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: This was mentioned (and attributed to Beverly Rowe) in Douglas R. Hofstadter's *Scientific American* column. It can be found in his book *Metamagical Themas: Questing for the Essence of Mind and Pattern*, Section I.2, *Self-Referential Sentences: A Follow-Up.* [(screen shot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lTkdc.png).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bourbaki was right :-)   On the other hand, let   $(X\ \le)$   be a partially ordered set. In general the family

$$\mathbf B\ \ :=\ \ \{\ ]x,\rightarrow[\ :\ x\in X\ \}$$

is NOT a topological base for any topology in   $X$.   One reason is trivial: no minimal element belongs to any member of   $B$;   thus if there is any minimal element then   $X$   would not be open.

OK, one could define:

$$\mathbf B\ \ :=\ \ \{X\}\ \cup\ \{\ ]x,\rightarrow[\ :\ x\in X\ \}$$

It will not help. Indeed, here is a characterization of a topological base:

**THEOREM**   A family   $\mathbf B$   of subsets of   $X$   is a topological base for a topology in   $X\quad\Leftrightarrow$   the following two conditions hold:

- $\bigcup \mathbf B\ =\ X$
- $\forall_{G\ H\in\mathbf B}\quad G\cap H\ =\ \bigcup\ \{K\in \mathbf B : K\subseteq G\cap H\}  $

Now consider a 5-element set

$$X := \{b\ \ d\ \ A\ \ C\ \ E\}$$

where by definition there are exactly four sharp inequalities   $b < A$   &   $b < C$   &   $d < C$   &   $d < E$.   Then the intersection

$$ ]b,\rightarrow[\ \ \cap\ \ ]d,\rightarrow[\quad=\quad \{ C \} $$

is not a union of any family of open rays   $ ]x,\rightarrow[ $.

Comment: May I know, please, what's wrong with my answer? @Reetesh Mukul wondered if Bourbaki should consider open intervals instead of closed intervals as a base of the left (or right) topology. I tried to explain that one would not get a topological base for general partially ordered space. Is it a crime on MO?

Comment: I am asking because my "Answer" has received a down-vote.

Comment: Not much mystery, I think: probably the downvoter would have upvoted instead "Bourbaki was wrong" :)

Answer (score 4):

Say we have a partially ordered set.  What do you doubt?  (1) The set of intervals $\left[x,\rightarrow\right[$ is a base for a topology.  (2) Any intersection of open sets is open.  (3) The closure of $\{x\}$ is $\left]\leftarrow,x\right]$.  They all look OK to me...

Comment: I solved this Exercise using the idea of Poset only, but then I got confused after reading the definition of right and left topology in Wiki: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/…. In General Topology -I, 1.4, while giving definition of Closed Set, Bourbaki says: On the rational line, every interval of the form [a,→[ is a closed set, for its complement ]←,a[ is open. But I agree that closed/open sets are subject to Topology under consideration.